# Angularjs modal window with routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm having trouble using routeProvider to display a modal window.  I am displaying a table list of ingredients and hoping that by clicking on an ingredient, I can display an "update" modal.  The table displays properly and I can even view a single ingredient outside of a modal context but as soon as I try and get the modal working everything falls apart - in fact, the modal doesn't even properly receive its "ingredient" variable.  When clicking on a table row the HTML for the modal is displayed like it's a separate page.

```
app.js:
```

angular.module('IngredientsApp', [
    'IngredientsApp.controllers',
    'IngredientsApp.services',
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.bootstrap'
]).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when("/ingredients", {templateUrl: "partials/ingredients.html", controller: "ingredientsController"}).
    when("/ingredient/:id", {templateUrl: "partials/ingredient.html", controller: "ingredientController"}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/ingredients'});
}]);

```
services.js:
```

angular.module('IngredientsApp.services', []).factory('ingredientAPIservice', function($http) {

```
var ingredientAPI = {};

ingredientAPI.getIngredients = function() {
    return $http.get('/ingredient');
}

ingredientAPI.getIngredient = function(id) {
  return $http.get('/ingredient/'+id+'/edit');
}

return ingredientAPI;
```

});

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Our Recipes</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/services.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body ng-app="IngredientsApp">
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

ingredients.html

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Existing Ingredients</th>
            <th><input type="text" ng-model="descriptionFilter" placeholder="Search..."/></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="i in ingredientsList | filter: searchFilter">
            <td>
                <a href="/#/ingredient/{{i.Id}}">
                    {{i.Description}}
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>Created at {{i.CreatedAt}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

ingredient.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        {{ingredient.Description}}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Dismiss</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

```
controllers.js:
```

angular.module('IngredientsApp.controllers', []).controller('ingredientsController', function($scope, ingredientAPIservice) {

```
$scope.descriptionFilter = null;
$scope.ingredientsList = [];


$scope.searchFilter = function (ingredient) {
    var keyword = new RegExp($scope.descriptionFilter, 'i');
    return !$scope.descriptionFilter || keyword.test(ingredient.Description);
};

ingredientAPIservice.getIngredients().success(function (response) {

    //Dig into the responde to get the relevant data
    $scope.ingredientsList = response;
});
```

})

var ingredientController = function($scope, $routeParams, $modal, ingredientAPIservice) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
    $scope.ingredient = null;

```
ingredientAPIservice.getIngredient($scope.id).success(function (response) {
    $scope.ingredient = response;
    $scope.open = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({

            templateUrl: 'partials/ingredient.html',
            controller: 'ingredientModalController',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                ingredient: function () {
                    console.log($scope.ingredient);
                    return $scope.ingredient;
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

var ingredientModalController = function($scope, $modalInstance, ingredient) {
    $scope.ingredient = ingredient;

```
$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.ingredient);
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is in app.js.  Your route change causes the modal template (partials/ingredients.html) to be the **only** template displayed in ui-view.  For the modal to work, you need to have the ingredients template nested within the ingredient template so both templates can be displayed at the same time. There are multiple ways to accomplish this.

1. If you are willing to give up the route change, just remove

   `when("/ingredient/:id", {templateUrl: "partials/ingredient.html", controller: "ingredientController"})`
2. If you need the url to change, then I would look at doing it manually through the build in location service. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

You could just call a function that changes the url on click of an ingredient.

Comment: So are you saying it's impossible to have the modal markup exist in a partial view?  Simply removing the line you referenced doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I'm saying that your current setup is going to remove all other templates when you go to "/ingredient/:id".  Removing the line was the first step.  You still have to integrate your two templates and the logic into one

Comment: Did this explanation help?

Comment: Sorry, no, I found it was a number of issues, the main one being I didn't actually provide an `ng-click="functionName();"` attribute in my modal trigger link.  I ended up able to leave my HTML templates as separate files, but I did converge the two controllers into one as I found I was unable to pass the selected ID from the parent to the child at this point in my Angular knowledge.